# Update custom module database - 7 shops same theme, plugins ect but fail at one shop

Tags: module, database, database-update

I just made an update to my custom module. 
My module store some data from a form, to my datatable. and the update should add a new culumn to my table.

It works fine on 6 shops, but fails on the last one.

So my quesstin is, why can it fail on just one shop, when they have the same setup, and how to fix et?

I know to make and update you have to chance the version number in ect/moduls, and in the config.

They have the new version number. but i can se in the core_recorce table, that its not updated why is that?

Comment: The Question is not clear,Please elaborate

Comment: I have altered my question

Comment: Any specific cache setup on that shop ?

Comment: no same as the other